# returning Entity class in response body throws Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**Summary**

Using Spring Boot version 3.1.4 and Java version 17, with H2 Embedded database and Spring Data JPA, trying an example implementation of *bookmyshow.com* API.

Getting `Infinite recursion - Stackoverflow error` when hitting the POST endpoint (The controller endpoint is returning `ResponseEntity<Bookings>` entity as response).

```
Request processing failed: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
```

*- The entire stack trace is mentioned below*

However, if the Controller endpoint is made to return `ResponseEntity<String>`, there is no exception and it works fine. Why there is this exception when I try to return JPA entity class in response body? How to resolve this?

**POST Request**

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://localhost:8080/api/v1/booking/book-seats' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "theatreId": 1,
  "seatNumbers": [
    "1A"
  ],
  "showId": 1,
  "userId": 1
}'
```

The entire code base can be cloned at https://github.com/vasant-techie/bookmyshow.git.

**Details**

**application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

**application-dev.properties**

```
debug=true

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

#JPA Configuration
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

# H2 Configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:bms
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=bms
spring.datasource.password=securebms
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
#spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true

# https|ssl Configuration
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:certificate.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=1234

# Enable | Disable Security
security.basic.enabled=true
management.security.enabled=true
```

**BookingController.java**

```
package com.bookmyshow.consumer.api.endpoints;

import com.bookmyshow.consumer.api.dto.BookingDetails;
import com.bookmyshow.consumer.api.entity.Bookings;
import com.bookmyshow.consumer.api.service.BookingService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/booking")
public class BookingController {

    private final BookingService bookingService;

    @Autowired
    public BookingController(BookingService bookingService) {
        this.bookingService = bookingService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/book-seats", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Bookings> bookSeats(@RequestBody BookingDetails bookingDetails) {
        Bookings bookings = bookingService.bookSeats(bookingDetails);
        return ResponseEntity.status(201).body(bookings);
    }
}
```

**BookingService.java**

```
package com.bookmyshow.consumer.api.service;

import com.bookmyshow.consumer.api.dto.BookingDetails;
import com.bookmyshow.consumer.api.entity.*;
import com.bookmyshow.consumer.api.repo.BookingRepository;
import com.bookmyshow.consumer.api.repo.SeatBookingsRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class BookingService {

    private final BookingRepository bookingRepository;
    private final SeatBookingsRepository seatBookingsRepository;
    private final ShowService showService;
    private final UserService userService;
    private final TheatreSeatService theatreSeatService;

    @Autowired
    public BookingService(BookingRepository bookingRepository, SeatBookingsRepository seatBookingsRepository, ShowService showService, UserService userService, TheatreSeatService theatreSeatService) {
        this.bookingRepository = bookingRepository;
        this.seatBookingsRepository = seatBookingsRepository;
        this.showService = showService;
        this.userService = userService;
        this.theatreSeatService = theatreSeatService;
    }

    public Bookings bookSeats(BookingDetails bookingDetails) {
        Show show = showService.findShowByShowId(bookingDetails.getShowId());
        Customer user = userService.findByUserId(bookingDetails.getUserId());
        List<TheatreSeat> theatreSeats = bookingDetails.getSeatNumbers().stream().map(theatreSeatService::findBySeatNo).toList();
        List<SeatBookings> seatBookings = theatreSeats.stream().map(seat -> new SeatBookings(seat, show)).toList();
        Bookings bookings = new Bookings(show, user, seatBookings);
        bookingRepository.save(bookings);
        // Set the relationship with the booking for each seat booking
        for (SeatBookings seatBooking : seatBookings) {
            seatBooking.setBookings(bookings);
        }

        // Save the seat bookings with the updated relationship
        seatBookingsRepository.saveAll(seatBookings);

        return bookings;
    }

}
```

**Bookings.java**

```
package com.bookmyshow.consumer.api.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "bookings", schema = "bms")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Bookings {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "bookingid")
    private Long bookingId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "showid")
    private Show show;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid")
    private Customer user;

    @Transient
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bookings", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<SeatBookings> seatBookings;

    @Column(name = "bookingdate", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate bookingDate;

    @Column(name = "amount", nullable = false)
    private int amount;

    @Column(name = "created", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @Column(name = "modified", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime modified;

    public Bookings(Show show, Customer user, List<SeatBookings> seatBookings) {
        this.show = show;
        this.user = user;
        this.bookingDate = LocalDate.now();
        this.amount = show.getTicketCost() * seatBookings.size();
        this.seatBookings = seatBookings;
        this.created = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.modified = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

**SeatBookings.java**

```
package com.bookmyshow.consumer.api.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "seatbookings", schema = "bms")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SeatBookings {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "seatbookingid", nullable = false)
    private Long seatBookingId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "bookingid")
    private Bookings bookings;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "showid")
    private Show show;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "seatid")
    private TheatreSeat theatreSeat;

    public SeatBookings(TheatreSeat seat, Show show) {
        this.theatreSeat = seat;
        this.show = show;
    }
}
```

**BookingRepository.java**

```
package com.bookmyshow.consumer.api.repo;

import com.bookmyshow.consumer.api.entity.Bookings;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface BookingRepository extends JpaRepository<Bookings, Long> {
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
}

group = 'com.bookmyshow.consumer.api'
version = '0.1'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2022.0.4")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
2023-10-13T07:10:05.932+05:30 DEBUG 1436 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [com.bookmyshow.consumer.api.entity.Bookings@a432c98]
2023-10-13T07:10:05.941+05:30 DEBUG 1436 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select t1_0.theatreid,t1_0.seatid,t1_0.created,t1_0.modified,t1_0.seatno,t1_0.status from bms.theatreseats t1_0 where t1_0.theatreid=?
2023-10-13T07:10:05.983+05:30  WARN 1436 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failure while trying to resolve exception [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.checkCommitted(ResponseFacade.java:503) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:347) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
... 
2023-10-13T07:10:05.989+05:30 DEBUG 1436 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)
2023-10-13T07:10:05.992+05:30 ERROR 1436 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root-cause**: Serialization issue

**Solution:**

To use `@JsonManagedReference`, `@JsonBackReference`

- `@JsonManagedReference` is the forward part of reference, the one
  that gets serialized normally.
- `@JsonBackReference` is the back part
  of reference; it’ll be omitted from serialization.

*Reference:* https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

**Fix:**

**Bookings.java**

```
package com.bookmyshow.consumer.api.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "bookings", schema = "bms")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Bookings {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "bookingid")
    private Long bookingId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonManagedReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "showid")
    private Show show;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonManagedReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid")
    private Customer user;

    @Transient
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bookings", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<SeatBookings> seatBookings;

    @Column(name = "bookingdate", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate bookingDate;

    @Column(name = "amount", nullable = false)
    private int amount;

    @Column(name = "created", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @Column(name = "modified", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime modified;

    public Bookings(Show show, Customer user, List<SeatBookings> seatBookings) {
        this.show = show;
        this.user = user;
        this.bookingDate = LocalDate.now();
        this.amount = show.getTicketCost() * seatBookings.size();
        this.seatBookings = seatBookings;
        this.created = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.modified = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bookings{" +
                "bookingId=" + bookingId +
                ", show=" + show +
                ", user=" + user +
                ", seatBookings=" + seatBookings +
                ", bookingDate=" + bookingDate +
                ", amount=" + amount +
                ", created=" + created +
                ", modified=" + modified +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**SeatBookings.java**

```
package com.bookmyshow.consumer.api.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "seatbookings", schema = "bms")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SeatBookings {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "seatbookingid", nullable = false)
    private Long seatBookingId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "bookingid")
    private Bookings bookings;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "showid")
    private Show show;

    @OneToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "seatid")
    private TheatreSeat theatreSeat;

    public SeatBookings(TheatreSeat seat, Show show) {
        this.theatreSeat = seat;
        this.show = show;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SeatBookings{" +
                "seatBookingId=" + seatBookingId +
                ", bookings=" + bookings +
                ", show=" + show +
                ", theatreSeat=" + theatreSeat +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the prefered solution (and considered good practice!) is to use DTOs and send only the required data to the frontend, not the entire entity.

Comment: Thanks @Chaosfire for sharing this useful info. I will update the code to use DTOs instead of entity class